# primevue fill datatable with protobuf

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, primevue

I fetch data as google protobuf format from server .
but can not understand how can fill primevue datatable columns .
this is my example code :

```
<template>
  <Card>
    <template #content>
      <DataTable
        :value="statisticList"
        :paginator="true"
        :rows="10"
        :rowsPerPageOptions="[10, 20, 50]"
        class="p-datatable-sm"
        paginatorTemplate="CurrentPageReport FirstPageLink PrevPageLink PageLinks NextPageLink LastPageLink RowsPerPageDropdown"
        responsiveLayout="scroll"
        stripedRows
        showGridlines
      >
        <Column field="getId()" header="Id" :sortable="true"></Column>
        <Column field="getSymbol()" header="Symbol"></Column>
        <template #paginatorLeft>
          <Button
            type="button"
            icon="pi pi-refresh"
            class="p-button-text"
            @click="getStatistics"
          />
        </template>
      </DataTable>
    </template>
  </Card>
</template>

<script>
import { statisticSubject } from "../../services/SubjectService";
import { requestStatistic } from "../../services/WebsocketService";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      statisticList: null,
    };
  },
  created() {
    requestStatistic();
    statisticSubject.subscribe((e) => (this.statisticList = e));
  },
  methods: {
    getStatistics() {
      requestStatistic();
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

this is part of my protobuf structure :

```
syntax = "proto3";
message StatisticBuffer {
  int64 id = 1;
  string symbol = 2;
  string exchange = 3;
}
```

**Note :**
data fetch and loaded without any problem buy primevue does not fill columns .

How can fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed**
Change code to this :

```
statisticSubject.subscribe((e) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
        this.statisticList[i] = e[i].toObject();
      }
});
```